# C Program behaves differently if compiled using CLion rather than using gcc directly. Why?

Tags: c, gcc, clion

I'm writing a program to play 4 in a row using C90.

I made a UI for the Console using ASCII characters.

If I compile the program using C Lion I get the following output:

[image: Screenshot C Lion Output]

If I compile it using gcc main.c and then run ./a.out I get the following result:

[image: Screenshot Terminal Output]

So obviously this dot character is sized differently if I compile it using gcc directly.

Has anyone any idea how this could possibly happen?

The code that is responsible for printing the game lines looks like this:

```
void printGameLine(int line[7]) {
    int i;
    printf("┃");
    for (i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        printColor(line[i]);
        line[i] == 0 ? printf("    ") : printf(" ⬤ ");
        printColor(0);
        printf("┃");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The code responsible for the colors looks like this: (If this makes any difference)

```
/**
 * prints the color
 * @param player -1 First player, 0 neutral, 1 Second Player
 */
void printColor(int player) {
    switch (player) {
        case 1:
            printf("\033[0;31m"); /*red*/
            break;
        case -1:
            printf("\033[0;33m");/*yellow*/
            break;
        default:
            printf("\033[0m");/*neutral*/
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the text editor. The first `printf()` has 4 spaces but `printf(" ⬤ ")` has 3 characters. Try using an `'O'`.

Comment: Probably the dot in `printf(" ⬤ ");` is interpreted differently by different compilers.

Comment: Look what sequence of bytes is generated by `" ⬤ "` on both compilers and you'll probably find out.

Comment: Possible... but thing is: I use gcc in both cases... its the same compiler

Comment: But is it the same text editor?

Comment: Is it the same gcc inboth cases? Try out what I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: Where can I see the exact bytes that are outputted?

Comment: And yes its the same gcc version

Comment: The return value from `printf` tells the number of characters printed.

Comment: It seems that in the second case a non-fixed-width font was used for the dot. And I believe the dot is a Unicode character. UTF-8 was standardized in 2003 and was first introduced in 1993. No way C90 in 1990 could know what UTF-8 characters are. I am wondering that you can compile it at all.

Comment: So I am able to compile it and if I print the count of bytes printed I get exactly the same in both cases

Comment: Are you running the executable you compiled from CLion in the same console you're running the version you manually compiled from? Might just be a difference in fonts.

Comment: yes its the same console... both times the clion terminal

Comment: Write a simple program doing only `printf(" ⬤ ");` and then pipe it into `hexdump`

Comment: Look what sequence of bytes is generated by " ⬤ " . You need to write a one liner for this (maybe 2 lines).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the font choice for the CLion Console.

- Go to File/[Settings...] then Editor/[Color Scheme]/[Console Font]
- Disable the "Use console font instead of the default" checkbox
- Choose a proper monospaced font of your choice (I use Fira Code)

[image: Configuration screenshot]

After that ensure to use same-length strings for both the empty and the "ball'd" positions.

Comment: I've reproduced your issue and fixed it doing the steps above.

Try printing "mmm\niii\n" on the console. If the length of the printed strings is different that means you are still using some proportional font on your console:

Proportional: "mmm"/"iii"; Monospaced: "`mmm`"/"`iii`"

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/au7gsoj58oxe4eh/AAC0bYGFZN8m0OD9ZZ8EoJtha?dl=0

The working image was if I ran the code directly using the play button. The other image is what happened after I ran the same file in the same console using "./..../ForInARow" command

Comment: I see. Looks like U+2b24 is a "bad-behaving" character in the monospaced fonts universe, it is both wider and spills over the next character (that explains why space following looks thinner). You could, perhaps, replace it by U+25cf (or the slightly less illbehaved U+26ab). They do not look that nice, but behave consistently to the monospace expectations. This snippet shows how bad it behaves: `printf("\niii\nmmm\n⬤⬤⬤\n   ⬤\n●●● U+25cf\n   ●\n⚫⚫⚫ U+26ab\n   ⚫");`. Another solution could be to print a black-on-black U+2b24 on the blank cells, but my attempt using `"\033[0;30m"` did not work.